# How to custom field in Capacity page of Azure Devops board?

Tags: azure-devops

I want to add Tags in the capacity page to filter resources as per teams in Capacity page

I have added resources and their capacity across a program level, now I want to filter them as per their teams to view the capacity at team level. How to add tags in capacity page for the same.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you can't custom field in Capacity page.

> I want to filter them as per their teams to view the capacity at team
> level.

The capacity page in Boards->Sprint is shown as per team. You can change the team you want to see as the picture below:
[image]

You could refer to the [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/sprints/set-capacity?view=azure-devops&tabs=new-nav#set-capacity-for-the-team-and-team-members) for more details.